# boost python optional raises an error

Tags: c++, constructor, boost-python

I have the following code:

```
//test.cpp
#include <Physical_file.h>
#include <boost\python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;
using namespace FMS_Physical;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(python_bridge)
{
    class_<Physical_file, boost::noncopyable>("pf")
        .def(init<const string&, optional<int, const string&>>())
    ;
}

//Physical_file.h
#include <fstream>
#include "tools.h"
using namespace std;

namespace FMS_Physical
{
    class Physical_file
    {
    public:
        fstream filefl;
        string workingDir;
        string fileName;
        int fileSize;
        block currBlock;
        block FHBuffer;
        bool opened;
        string openMode;

        /************
        functions
        ************/

        Physical_file(void);
        Physical_file(const string &FileName, int FileSize,const string &Dir = getCurrentPath());
        Physical_file(const string &FileName, const string &Type, const string &Dir = getCurrentPath());

        ~Physical_file(void);
    };
}
```

there is some more code, I think it's irrelevant to the question.

when I try to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
Error   5   error C2664: 'FMS_Physical::Physical_file::Physical_file(const FMS_Physical::Physical_file &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::string' to 'const FMS_Physical::Physical_file &'
```

when I delete the `optional` from the definition of the constructor (in test.cpp) the error disappears, but I don't get the optional parameters.

I'm compiling using VS2010, python27 and c++ boost libs.

Can any one explain why I get this error and how can I solve it?

**EDIT** 
I tried exposing the third constructor instead using the following line:

```
.def(init<const string&, const string &, optional<const string &>>())
```

this didn't cause any errors.

Comment: I think you should keep boiling the broken code down until you have just a few lines.  It'll help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to give a default to `FileSize`.
For this declaration to work: `init<const string&, optional<int, const string&>>`
you need a constructor that can be called with only a `const string&` parameter. You do not have such at the moment, which is the exact complaint of the compiler.